# How to change a group name (sAMAccountName) in ADS?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm Trying to change a name of a group with c# and .NET. It's working well with the following code:

```
    public void selectADSObject(string LDAP)
    {
        DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry(ADS_PATH);
        Entry.Username = ADS_USER;
        Entry.Password = ADS_PW;
        DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry);
        Searcher.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
        Searcher.Filter = LDAP;
        AdObj = Searcher.FindOne();
        AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry().Rename("cn=newName");
    }
```

There is just the "windows-pre 2000" name that doesn't rename and I need it to rename too. On [this](http://www.selfadsi.de/img/tutorial/ad-w2k8-group-attributes-01.png) page I figured out that the `sAMAccountName` is what I'm after. But when I add the following lines, it also doesn't change the pre-windows 2000 name:

```
AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "newName";
AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry().CommitChanges();
```

How can I change the sAMAccountName / pre-windows 2000 name?

Comment: Try putting the samaccountname change before the rename().  Issue two commitchanges() one after the samaccountname assignment and one after the rename().  There are some constraints for samaccountname in AD.

Comment: @decompiled: still just change the cn and not the sAMAccountName / pre-windows 2000 name :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you invoke:

```
AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry()
```

It actually creates a new object! Every change is lost on the next line. Please use something like:

```
var dent = AdObj.GetDirectoryEntry()
dent.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "newName";
dent.CommitChanges();
dent.rename("cn=newName");
```